# Logout from Instgram in my website

Tags: logout, instagram-api

I have integrated login with Instagram feature in my website using provided API successfully. 
Now i have implement the feature of logout from Instagram and then website should redirect to home page of website. But I am not getting a way to do this, please help me in this matter. I have tried lots of solutions given by other people.

Answer (score 0):

First : Destroy all session variables of website on logout page to logout from your website.

Second: Use below JavaScript code to logout from Instagram

```
         var s = document.createElement("script");
         s.src = "https://instagram.com/accounts/logout";
         $("head").append(s);
```